# UK visit visa with an ongoing bank loan

Tags: visas, uk

I have an ongoing bank loan and I have been paying monthly installments for it for more than a year now. I recently got a top-up on the loan (in July), which means a big transaction in the bank statement. This is my salary account where my salary is deposited.

I want to apply for a UK visit visa this month as well. My account had sufficient funds to cover the cost of the trip prior to the top-up. And the reason for top-up is not to cover the cost of the trip. Will it be considered as funds parking? Given that the loan was ongoing and I just had a top-up.

I have visited the UK twice previously and have a good travel history (including the US).

Comment: The timing seems suspicious, especially if your account does not otherwise indicate the means to afford such a trip.

Comment: Sorry. I failed to mention that my account had sufficient funds for the cost of the trip prior to top-up amount disbursal. And the reason for top-up is not to cover the cost of the trip.

Answer (score 2):

> And the reason for top-up is not to cover the cost of the trip. Will it be considered as funds parking?

Provide the proper documentary proof of this incoming transaction and a reason as to why this has come in at a time you are printing your bank statements. Also provide evidence of the fact that you can afford the trip without that money and explain that you do not intend to spend that money on your trip.

And there is no reason it will be considered funds parking then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can include the loan top-up letter from the bank. What evidence do you suggest to explain that I do not intend to spend the loan money on the trip? Will it be sufficient to provide all the details on a covering letter?